# Multiple conditions in while loop failing because of input type in Bash, or 3 digit number condition required

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop

I am trying to control the user input to a script so that a only 3 digit number can pass. I started with two ifs and these work fine.

```
echo -e "Input sequence number:"
read SEQUENCE

NUMTEST='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $SEQUENCE =~ $NUMTEST ]]; then
    echo "ERROR:" "$SEQUENCE" "is not a number! Try again!"
    exit 1
fi

SEQLEN=$(printf "%s" "$SEQUENCE" | wc -c)  
if (($SEQLEN != 3)); then
    echo "ERROR:" "$SEQUENCE" "is not a 3 digit number! Try again!"
    exit 1
fi
```

A nicer solution would be to use a while loop so the user doesn't have to keep re-running the script, but whilst I can get a while loop to work for each individual condition, when I combine them a text input kills the loop as the numerical condition doesn't like it.

```
echo -e "Input sequence number:"
read SEQUENCE

NUMTEST='^[0-9]+$'
SEQLEN=$(printf "%s" "$SEQUENCE" | wc -c)

while ! [[ $SEQUENCE =~ $NUMTEST ]] && (($SEQLEN != 3)); do
    echo "ERROR:" "$SEQUENCE" "is not a 3 digit number! Try again!"
    echo -e "Input sequence number:"
    read SEQUENCE    
    SEQLEN=$(printf "%s" "$SEQUENCE" | wc -c)
done
```

I'm thinking either I need to create a single condition $SEQUENCE == 3 digit number or find a way to suppress the errors such that any error mean the loop continues.

To be explicit my questions are:

- Is there a way to write the condition $SEQUENCE == 3 digit number?
- Can i suppress the error and still go to the loop, or is this a script terminating error?

Suggestions and improvements much appreciated. This is my first script so I won't be surprised if I'm committing some poor practices so any other recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to write the condition $SEQUENCE == 3 digit number?

Yes. Change your regex to `^[0-9]{3}`.

With a small trick you can also remove the duplicated input processing:

```
while true; do
    read -p 'Input sequence number: ' sequence
    [[ "$sequence" =~ ^[0-9]{3}$ ]] && break
    echo "ERROR: '$sequence' is not a 3 digit number!"
done
```

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you for your input. Wasn't sure whether `{3}` would work with `=~` regexes. I did not use `while read` because then the user would be able to slip any  string through the validation by pressing ctrl+d twice.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you @Socowi! That's a much neater solution! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean:

```
while ! [[ $SEQUENCE =~ $NUMTEST ]] || (($SEQLEN != 3)); do
```

You need to loop again when not a number or not three digit (which is different from your construct, where you loop when not a number and length is not three).

Also, you can create a regexp for amtching three-digit numbers, as stated in @Socowi's answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right thanks! Totally missed that, and it works with that correction. Much appreciated.